# Why does 'std::function<void()>' take a lambda returning 'bool' without any warning?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, generics, lambda

```
#include <functional>

void f()
{
    // warning: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void'
    return true; 
}

std::function<void()> fn = [] { return true; }; // no warning

int main()
{}
```

**Why does** `std::function<void()>` **take a lambda returning** `bool` **without any warning?**

Comment: It's probably not, because the lambda function is never instantiated at all. See here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e183d9a4dcbf4ca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's how it's designed. If the return type in the template argument is `void`, it ignores the return type of the functor.

This is in line with how `std::is_invocable_r` works.

Also, it would be hard for a (non-magical) class to emit a *warning*. (Unlike failing with an error, which is easy.) Not to mention that the standard doesn't differentiate warnings from errors.

Comment: we need a `static_warning` standardized. there are unportable ways to emit a warning, using deprecated prefs, but that all implementation's land.

Answer (score 1):

That's its job: it handles impedance matching between the declared type of the `function` object and the callable object that it holds.

Ordinary pointers to function are strictly typed:

```
int f(double);
double g(int);

int x = f(3.2); // OK
long y = f(3);  // OK: argument and return type get converted

int (*ptr)(double);
ptr = f; // OK: f is pointer to function taking double and returning int
ptr = g; // error: types don't match
```

`std::function` handles type mismatches, so type conversions look more like what you expect in a function call:

```
std::function<int(double)> func;
func = f; // OK
func = g; // OK: argument and return type get converted internally
```

This flexibility comes at a cost, so when you are dealing with exact types you should use function pointers and not `std::function`.